# Getting correct axis sub-divisions when zooming in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am wondering how to approach creating the ticks for a zoomable chart that represents musical information.

I would like to have a chart with 4 ticks [0-1-2-3-4] on the X Axis that as it is zoomed will sub-divide each tick in half to give [0-0.5-1-1.5-2-2.5....] then half again to give [0-0.25-0.5-0.75-1...] and so on.

The current default behaviour seems to be to divide between integers first by half, then into fifths.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour using a function or would I need to set the ticks manually taking into account the scale and transform values of my chart?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you could achieve this behaviour by setting the zoom "levels" (i.e. scale factors) appropriately.

Comment: I have set up a chart that zooms using the mouse as per the programmatic pan + zoom example here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892928. As it scales in and out of the chart the tick values I require are never shown.

Comment: You can also, as you say, set the tick values explicitly.